# JQuery is not defined after installing cached-resources in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I use ggts 3.3.3 Kepler, Grails 2.3.3 OSX 10.8.4.
After installing cached-resources I got the following console errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 2E8CFq9qq9Hd3oC8Vm4eO2E0N1BbHOBaOBasevchm9s.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined lGOHo6E45gxva6dsPhjXSefA7yz16IHSaQv0fiWoM7W.js:5
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Why can jquery not be found anymore? Nothing else has changed.

my config.groovy:

```
    application { 
      dependsOn 'jquery'
      resource url:'/js/application.js' 
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your gsp and resources config?

Comment: Make sure `application` module is imported into your gsp.

Comment: This is imported as before but with the plugin in get this error. My solution is to load jquery externally. Is there a better way?